# Exact same data one running, another not running in an lm() like function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe

When I run my function call `robu()` using `dat1` data.frame, the function runs perfectly fine. However, when I extract EXACTLY the same data from a larger data.frame and call it `dat2` the same `robu()` call fails!

Am I missing anything here? (*fully reproducible code appears below*)

```
library(robumeta)

dat1 <- data.frame(study.name = c("Guo", "Guo", "Guo"),
                         dint = c(0.8525524, 0.6801170, 0.7709437),
                           SD = c(0.3127318, 0.2994228, 0.3075567))

robu(dint~1, data = dat1, var = SD^2, study = study.name) ## Runs perfectly fine!!!!

d1 <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/v7.csv", h = T)

dat2 <- d1[100:102,1:3]  ### Exactly same data as `dat1`

robu(dint~1, data = dat2, var = SD^2, study = study.name) ## NOW FAILS ! `infinite or missing values in 'x'`
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the package you're using. But the "study.name" factor isn't quite the same. In `dat2`, it will have many more levels. Try `levels(dat2$study.name)` vs. `levels(dat1$study.name)`. Or perhaps re-level `dat2$study.name` and see if that suddenly works again?

Comment: If you run a sample with the full precision as in your file, for example using `dint = c(0.852552413754678, 0.680116978808277, 0.770943673708781),` it will also fail. I cannot tell you why. But if it continues to be an issue, you might want to re-frame the question and include the full precision of your sample using `dput(head(dat2))` so others can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can `round` the numeric columns to specific number of digits as those columns from 'dat1' and 'dat2' are not the same (`all.equal(dat1$dint, dat2$dint)`)

```
dat2[2:3] <- lapply(dat2[2:3], round, digits = 7)
robu(dint~1, data = dat2, var = SD^2, study = study.name) 
#RVE: Correlated Effects Model with Small-Sample Corrections 

#Model: dint ~ 1 

#Number of studies = 1 
#Number of outcomes = 3 (min = 3 , mean = 3 , median = 3 , max = 3 )
#Rho = 0.8 
#I.sq = 0 
#Tau.sq = 0 

#               Estimate                StdErr           t-value dfs P(|t|>) 95% #CI.L 95% CI.U Sig
#1 X.Intercept.    0.768 0.0000000000000000125 61358530816235696   1       0    #0.768    0.768 ***
#---
#Signif. codes: < .01 *** < .05 ** < .10 *
#---
```